# MySQL search and replace syntax error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following query and get the below error message:

```
update `wp_posts` set  `post_excerpt` = replace( `post_excerpt`, "[av_font_icon icon='ue82d' font='entypo-fontello' size='14px' position='left' color='' custom_class=''][/av_font_icon]", '') where instr( `post_excerpt`, "[av_font_icon icon='ue82d' font='entypo-fontello' size='14px' position='left' color='' custom_class=''][/av_font_icon]") > 0;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"[av_font_icon icon='ue82d' font='entypo-fontello' size='14px'
>   position='left' c' at line 1

I am trying to find the shortcode within my wordpress database and remove it.  Does anyone know what is wrong?  many thanks

Comment: Do you use phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes thats where I am running the query

Comment: IN your error message I see 3 quotes at the beginning,make sure they are double quotes

Comment: tried that also, still get same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the "Database Search And Replace Script In PHP"? All you have to do is place it in the root folder and run it in your browser. 
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

That's what I use and have never had a problem. Just make sure to make a back up just in case.

Run a search for the short code and replace it with an empty field.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the single quotes in the string you are matching, using `''`