# wp-cli search-replace command not searching and replacing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, config, wp-cli

I'm using wp-cli tool for searching and replacing the site's url to a new url.  I'm executing this command in command line in the directory of the wordpress installation:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\somewebsite>wp search-replace 'somewebsite.com' 'new_website.com'
```

the command does not issue any errors, and when i check the database with this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_value LIKE '%new_website.com%'
```

I get zero results.

I have the the username, password, db name, location set correctly in wp.config file.

**EDIT**

By any chance does this have to do with the sql file permissions?

**EDIT**
Ok it wp-cli did not work for me but https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ did.  Make sure you use the stable version as of this writing which is:  v2.1.0 STABLE.

Comment: what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ok it wp-cli did not work for me but https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ did.  Make sure you use the stable version as of this writing which is:  v2.1.0 STABLE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL search and replace syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592208/mysql-search-and-replace-syntax-error)

Comment: Was it a really big db? I am running into this with a dump file that is around 150 mb.

Answer (score 13):

I just had the same issue, and the problem was single quotes in the Windows command prompt - the following worked for me:

`wp search-replace "somewebsite.com" "new_website.com"`

Comment: OMG, spent an hour searching what's wrong...

Comment: BINGO. Confirmed cuplrit. In windows cmd, using " (double quotes) instead of ' (single quotes) made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. Try adding --verbose to the end of your search-replace command and check the output. All wp-cli search-replace options can be found here: http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/

Comment: k i tried adding --debug:  wp search-replace 'somewebsite.com' 'new_website.com'  --debug, and still same results.

Comment: by any chance does this have to do with the sql file permissions?

Comment: --verbose did not print anything, just goes back to new line in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your `wp-config.php` thoroughly. For me I was loading `wp-settings.php` twice which is the reason why there was no output at all because there were errors behind the scenes. You need to set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to see the errors and you can start fixing your `wp-config.php` from there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a while ago. As it turned out, I did not have the current wp-cli version installed. I was typing correct syntax, but the command was not executing, and no errors were returned.

`wp cli check-update`

`wp cli update`

after I updated to version 1.0 I no longer had any problems.

Just a thought.