# Search and Replace URLs with Dates

Tags: wordpress, replace

I'm looking to search and replace a bunch of URLs in Wordpress with this format:

www.domain.com/2009/03/7/post-name/ to www.domain.com/post-name/ yet I don't know how to search for all the different dates, is there an expression I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592208/mysql-search-and-replace-syntax-error/32596758#32596758 Use "Database Search And Replace Script In PHP"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you really need is other permalink settings, check on wordpress settings http://site.url/wp-admin/options-permalink.php